# Site Wide Class for Zend that can be used in actions, controllers and views?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can you create a site wide function for getting a role or region based on an id. 
Also things like returning a specific colour based on a calculation of (actual/target), in a view. 
I want to use it in a view and action.

I have tried, creating a class and setting it up in library:

```
class Colouring 
{
    /*
     * Array of the class for specifically the GEP portal theme
     */
    private $colours_class = array( 0 => 'color-grey',
                                1 => 'color-grey',
                                2 => 'color-orange',
                                3 => 'color-blue',
                                4 => 'color-green'
                            );

    /*
     * Returns colour based on actual and target
     */
    private static function getColour($actual, $target) 
    {
        ...return someValue

        }
}
```

Path: `Zend_Site/library/`

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Colouring' not found in
```

So then I thought Maybe a View_Helper is what I needed:

So I changed path to: `My/View/Helper/Colouring.php`
and Class to: `My_View_Helper_Colouring`
added this to config.ini: `resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper_ = "My/View/Helper/"`

I use:

```
$viewHelperObj = $this->view->getHelper('Colouring');
$viewHelperObj->getColour($this->value, $this->divisor);
```

Gives: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getHelper() on a non-object`

I tried also:

```
$this->getColour($this->value, $this->divisor);
```

Which Gives:

```
Plugin by name 'GetColour' was not found in the registry
```

So not really getting the idea of the correct practice to use to add static methods for things that are site wide, or even jsut a site wide class and the way to register. Would I use Plugins, View helpers, Action helpers or just striaght up classes.

I am using Zend 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to rename the method: `getColour()` `to Colouring()` and make it public.
Then try to call it from view like this:

```
echo $this->Colouring('biz', 'bazz');
```

Comment: I needed to add `$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/My/Views/Helpers','My_View_Helper');` in `bootstrap.php`. But it now gives `WARNING: CALL_USER_FUNC_ARRAY() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE A VALID CALLBACK, CANNOT ACCESS PRIVATE METHOD MY_VIEW_HELPER_COLOURING::COLOURING()`

Comment: Sorry that error was because I didn't change method to public